# Show logout button after login without refresh

Tags: jquery, laravel-5

I need to show logout button after login without page refresh.
So far I am thinking of jquery's .show() and .hide() on success in ajax.
But the problem is, the logout button is in another page, how to achieved this?

```
 @if(Auth::check())
    <a href="{{ url('/logout') }}" class="btn-logout" id="logged">Logout</a>
 @endif
```

in ajax success

```
 success: function(data) { 
     console.log(data);
     $("#logged").show();
     //var logg = ("#logged");
     var logg= parent.document.getElementById('logged'); 
                alert(logg); 

     console.log(logg)//null
     ......
```

I need to show logout button immediately after login
The login is inside modal and the id="logged" is int the main template

My login in modal

```
$("#login-form").on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log($(this).serialize());
        var datas = $(this).serialize();
        if($("#login-form #email").hasClass('has-error')) {
                $('#login-form #email').removeClass('has-error');
        }
        if($("#login-form #password").hasClass('has-error')) {
                $('#login-form #password').removeClass('has-error');
        }
        var green = $("#login-form .green")
        $.ajax({
            url: 'partA/user/login',
            data: datas,
            type: 'post',
            success: function(data) {
                var ht = window.opener.getElementById("logged");
                alert(ht);
                if (!data.errors) {
                    $("#static").modal('hide');
                    $("#logged").show();
                    toastr.info('You are now allowed to perform such operation');
                    startSessionTimer();
                    test = true;
                    $("#login").hide();
                } else {
                    $("#allowed").addClass('hide');
                    $("#notallowed").removeClass('hide');
                }
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(data) {
            }
        }).done(function(data) {
            if(!data.errors){
                var jeopardy_frame = $('iframe#jeopardy');
                var rotator_frame = $('iframe#rotator');
                jeopardy_frame[0].contentWindow.jSetRoles(data.roles);
                rotator_frame[0].contentWindow.jSetRoles(data.roles);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: `$(find("#logout");` is incorrect

Comment: lol i mean the syntax :)))

Comment: You could use php

Answer (score 0):

- You need to add that logout code (carefully) by default hide and show on successful login.

**If you need not to refresh that's the only way to do this by adding your code.**

- Other way is to merge that page and do hide and show game it would be bit complicated and expensive according to time consumption.

I would suggest first one. 
let me know if you need help on coding side as well.
Goodluck

Comment: Your first suggestion was actually what my code does.I just need to know on how to access the id of logout button so that I can show it after login without refreshing the page.The problem is that my login is modal which is automatically called when a user edits a certain part of an iframe, and the logout button is in the main layout.

Comment: 1. you can't access id without adding code (how you do it its up to you).

Comment: you can add layout to the login hide it by default which will solve your issue.

Comment: this is how i do it parent.document.getElementById('logged'); but return null

Comment: It's because it can't find the id logged.

Comment: yes, and thats the problem,tried window.parent.document.getElementById, and parent.parent.document.getEle...no luck

Comment: Html as well. thats why said whole page.

Comment: have you got what you were looking for.